# Hide virtual keyboard after selecting value on Select2 v3

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-3

I'm using select2 v.3.4.5 solely for my project. Currently, when viewing on mobile, the keyboard does not close after it open and value selected, I would like to close it thought. I would like open only when user focus on it and type something.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Salutation,#Gender').select2()
    .on('change select-open', function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.select2-input').blur();
      }, 500);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <h3>Application Form</h3>
      <form class="form" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="GivenName">Given Name:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="GivenName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Surname">Surname:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Surname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
          <select class="" name="" id="Salutation">
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
          <select class="" name="" id="Gender">
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As this js

```
    $('#Salutation,#Gender').select2()
    .on('change select2-open',function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.select2-input').blur();
        }, 500);
    });
```

I set input-search box to blur already but keyboard does not close.

How can I do to archive this purpose? Please kindly help. Thanks.

PS: Understandably, select2 v4 fixed this bug, yet I could not upgrade my select2 version since my project is solely depend on v3.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ensuring the search box does not autofocus

There is no way to do this well in Select2 - whenever you try to call the `blur()` function on this input, it just refocuses it.

However, by listening on the `open` event, we can replace the search box with our own one, that does not autofocus. Only the currently active search box has the class `select2-focused`, so we use that to find it, and then create a new search box (with the same `select2-input` class so it retains the same look and feel), and then re-implement the search feature ourselves, finally inserting that into the DOM, and removing the old search box.

## Not showing the keyboard after closing the selection popup

Select2 seems to try and implement its own `blur()` event in a very weird way (see [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1908#issuecomment-76546178)).

So, rather than try and use that, take advantage of CSS selectors. The `:focus` selector in CSS selects anything that has focus. Since Select2 doesn't actually add any new DOM elements (i.e. once in the HTML, it becomes standard `<div>` elements, `<input>` elements, etc), we can find the one that has focus, and successfully call blur on it.

Therefore, by calling `$(":focus").blur()`, we find the DOM element that currently has focus, and we blur it.

Also, by using `select2-close` as our event, rather than `change`, the keyboard won't open even if the user doesn't select an item, but instead clicks outside of it.

---

I have tested it, and it does work for me on an iPad running iOS 11. Here is the final, working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#Salutation,#Gender").select2().on("select2-open",()=>{
  let oldSearchBox = $(".select2-focused")[0]; //Get the current search box
  let parent = oldSearchBox.parentNode; //The parent of the search box (i.e. the element that holds it)

  let search = document.createElement("input"); //Create a new input box
  search.classList.add("select2-input"); //Make it look like the old one
  search.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{ //Whenever someone releases a key, filter the results
   let results = parent.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("select2-result"); //Get all of the select box options
   let query = search.value.toLowerCase(); //Get what the user has typed (in lower case so search is case-insensitive)
   for (let result of results) { //Loop through all of the select box options
    let resultText = result.children[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue.toLowerCase(); //Get the text for that option (also in lower case)
    result.style.display =  (resultText.indexOf(query)==-1) ? "none" : "block"; //If the result text contains the search, it is displayed, otherwise it is hidden
   }
  })
  
  parent.appendChild(search); //Add the new search box to the page
  oldSearchBox.remove(); //Remove the old one
 });
  
  $("#Salutation,#Gender").select2().on("select2-close",()=>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
   $(":focus").blur();
    }, 50);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <h3>Application Form</h3>
      <form class="form" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="GivenName">Given Name:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="GivenName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Surname">Surname:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Surname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
          <select class="" name="" id="Salutation">
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
          <select class="" name="" id="Gender">
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very much thanks, it works just great. By understanding this logic, I tried to add myself event `select2-open`, `select2-opening` to hide keyboard on opening select2 as well `$('#Salutation,#Gender').select2().on('change select2-open select2-opening',function(e){ $(':focus').blur();})`. But it does not work on opening. Would you mind helping on this? Then I will accept this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: If your okay with completely getting rid of the search box, (no point if you can't type in it, right), then [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmj4t50/32/) I wrote provides quite a nice solution. Otherwise, I will spend some time writing a better one.

Comment: thanks, it does not mean to remove search box, I thought by losing focus from search box on open select2 would not trigger keyboard pop up until we start focus and type something on it. :)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. There really is no way to this in Select2 - when the input box is blurred, it immediately refocuses it. **But** I have a solution, which you can view in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmj4t50/82/). It removes the search box, and replaces it with a new one, which doesn't autofocus. This works well when testing on my iPad.

Comment: sorry to be back here. I found a little issue on Tablet mobile phone, that just select option without typing anything in search box, the keyboard pop in and out quickly. looking forward to hearing from you, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative work around that I've been using for about a week now.  So far it seems to work well on all android and ios devices I've tried.  I use this on select2 instances that have 'multiple' set to false (i.e. 'single' type).  In this case, I want the user to make a single selection, and the the keyboard should disappear.

In short, during the select2-close event you set a flag that indicates that you want to disable any focus event the select2-focusser receives. When the focus event is triggered, you check if the flag is set and if so you simply move the focus to another target. I add the flag as a data property and I reset this flag after a second using a setTimeOut.

This works because the select2 close handler is split into 2 parts, and the 'select2-close' event is triggered at the end of part 1 (and before part 2).  Part 1 is the 'abstract' close handler, which actually closes the selection dialog, and sets the control's value.  Part 2 is the 'single' close handler, which really just causes the select2 to refocus on itself (which is the problem!).

For me, I added a '.focus-bait' class to one of my nav bar buttons, and I use this to divert focus during the focusser's focus event execution. If you have issues getting this refocus step to work, try a different element (I had a problem getting it to work on a button I had made for the purpose of focusing on.  I'm still not sure why, but I didn't investigate more as my nav button solution worked perfectly for my needs).

```
$('body').on('focus','.select2-focusser', function(e) { 
    let isDisabled = $(this).parent().first().data("disable-focus");
    if (isDisabled) {
        console.log('Focusser: focus event aborted');
       $('.focus-bait').focus();
    }   
});

//select2_focus_ctrl is a class that I add to any select2 container
//that I wish to use this focus logic e.g. add it to #Salutation,#Gender
$('body').on('select2-close','select2_focus_ctrl', function(e) {
    console.log('Focusser: disabling focus event');
    if ($(this).data('select2').opts.multiple != true) {
        $(this).prev().data("disable-focus",true);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log('Focusser: enabling focusser');
            $(this).prev().data("disable-focus",false);
        }, 1000);               
    }
});
```

Here is a full code snippet.  While writing it I noticed that if the select2 container is sourced from a 'select' element, the 'multiple' property does not exist (mine used a 'div'), so I've changed one line of code: `.opts.multiple != true` (instead of `== false`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#Salutation').select2(

);

    
$('body').on('focus','.select2-focusser', function(e) { 
    let isDisabled = $(this).parent().first().data("disable-focus");
    if (isDisabled) {
        console.log('Focusser: focus event aborted');
       $('.focus-bait').focus(); 
    }   
});

$('body').on('select2-close','.select2_focus_ctrl', function(e) {
    console.log('Focusser: disabling focus event');
    if ($(this).data('select2').opts.multiple != true) {
        $(this).prev().data("disable-focus",true);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log('Focusser: enabling focusser');
            $(this).prev().data("disable-focus",false);
     }, 1000);
    }
});


$('body').on('change','#Salutation', function(e) {
      let theVal = $('#Salutation').select2("val");
      $('#currentVal').val(theVal);
});
      
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #dddddd;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  background: #fff;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="focus-bait">
Just the bait!
</button>
<br>
<div>
<input id="currentVal"  style="height:20px;width:150px"/>
</div>

<br><br>

<select class="select2_focus_ctrl" id="Salutation" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
  <option value="Esquire">Esquire</option> 
  <option value="Other Options">Other Options</option> 
  <option value="Just for interest">Interesting longer item</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: thanks very much, I tried it but seem the keyboard won't hide after option selected, i tested on iphone. Could you add a full snippet please?